# C++ client interceptor experimental

Tags: grpc

gRPC appears to support C++ client interceptor, however the API is still under experimental nameapace (https://github.com/grpc/grpc/pull/16842).

Is there any plan to stablise/productionise the feature?

It's useful but I don't want to use experimental features.